# CRM pre-validation

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm very new to CRM and was looking into the CRM plugin event pipelines and wanted to create a few plugins for practice purposes. I created a plugin for pre-validation which will just set the account name (a mandatory field) to null. I assumed that this will just throw a validation error. But that's not happening, the entity is getting saved with an empty name. Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because name of account is not "Platform required" field. "Required" or fields with red asterisk are required only when you create/edit information from CRM UI.

Comment: That makes sense, so validation means it only checks for the fields which are system required? I set the owner to null and i'm getting an error.

Comment: That's because ownerid is "platform required" field. To understand metadata you should download SDK and find EntityMetadata excel spreadsheet that contains information about all OOB entities/fields/relationships.